# How can I call notify on a specific thread when I have put wait on many threads?

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, notify

I have a code where I create a thread per object at the start. Then I store the threads and the relevant objects in a hashmap. When a particular method is called, I need to get the thread from the hashmap using the object which called that method and execute some logic. Below is my method.

```
public void sendMessage(Message message) {
    for (Iterator<MessageListenerItem> iterator = messageListnerItemList.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
        MessageListenerItem messageListnerItem = (MessageListenerItem) iterator.next();
        Thread messageListenerThread = threadMessageListenerMap.get(messageListnerItem.getMl());
        System.out.println("The thread that is executing is : " + messageListenerThread.getName());
        this.messageListenerItem = messageListnerItem;
        this.message = message;
        messageListenerThread.start();
    }
}
```

So this if a method is received from object "A", then thread "A" will be started. But before the end of execution of thread "A", if object "A" calls this method again, then I will have to wait till the thread "A" end and then use it again for the 2nd call. But in the mean time if Object "B" calls this method it will get its Thread "B" from the hashmap and use it. So if I use wait-notify, how can I notify only Thread B once its execution is complete and not Thread A. How can I achieve this? Please advice.

Comment: Have the "thread" manage it's own internal/blocking queue, so your method simply keeps adding messages to the thread's queue and it keeps popping them out, waiting when there are none

Comment: Just wake all the threads. Your code has to handle spurious wakeups anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Wait/notify is too crude a mechanism for what you want to achieve.

You will have to set some flag or something so that ThreadB needs to know that the notify was not addressed to it. And use `notifyAll`.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use a different monitor for each thread?